# how to get CLion IdeaVIM ^O binding back to return from 'gd' goto def?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, clion, ideavim

I'm on a new installation of CLion with the IdeaVIM plugin working in Rust.

I successfully used the 'gd' goto definition motion and the ^O to return once.

I was then immediately prompted with something like "vim key usage detected - I selected "IDE keys ( or something IDE...)", incorrectly guessing what it wanted.  And now 'gd' works but I can't return via ^O.

What sticky settings have I put in place to break 'gd' ^O?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update this key in vim settings. For that click the vim icon in the status bar -> `Settings...`

[image]